# Connect after routed component causing boolean values in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am currently building an app with React, React Router and React Redux

Versions:

React - v15.5.4

React Router - v4.0

React Redux - v.5.0.6

I am new to React and even newer to Redux and right when I got my head around the connect HOC I started to have this error that I cant seem to figure out.

When I connect a component to my redux store after a `<switch>` element and some `<Route>` elements. My connect within that returns my props as false boolean values where as the component within the connect has the correct props.

See code and error below for example.

Component

```
UserDashboardPage = connect(state => {
  console.log("STATE", state);
  return {
    user: state.user.user,
    userAuth: state.user.userAuth,
    userFetched: state.user.fetched
  };
})(UserDashboardPage);

UserDashboardPage.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.shape(),
  userAuth: PropTypes.shape(),
  userFetched: PropTypes.boolean,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func
};
```

CONSOLE LOG STATE
[image]
Connect with boolean prop values
[image]
Component with correct props
[image]

ERROR:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the local `UserDashboardPage` variable with the result of calling `connect()`. You then set PropTypes on the component returned by `connect()`.

While you can do that, what you want in this case is to set the PropTypes of the wrapped component, not the wrapper component. Just swapping the order of execution will do it:

```
UserDashboardPage.propTypes = {

};

UserDashboardPage = connect(state => {
  ...
})(UserDashboardPage);
```

But you may want to consider using a different variable name for one component or the other, e.g.

```
UserDashboardPage.propTypes = {

};

const ConnectedUserDashboardPage = connect(state => {
  ...
})(UserDashboardPage);
```

This is usually not a problem since most people just immediately export the connected component as the default export:

```
export default connect(...)
```

The `false` values you're seeing are from React assigning default values to those props that failed validation. And they will always fail validation since those props are pulled from context, not passed down as normal props.

Comment: Doh! Totally makes sense! Thanks. Thought it was something lame like that.

Answer (score 0):

why are you passing UserDashboardPage into connect? This should be your non connected component